# front-end just remove only last item in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a issue with React.
my parent component:

```
class RoomPrice extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      room: this.props.room,
      prices: []
    };
    this.handleDeletePrice = this.handleDeletePrice.bind(this);

  }
  handleDeletePrice(price_index){
    let prices = this.state.prices;
    prices.splice(price_index, 1);
    this.setState({prices: prices});
  }

  listPrices(){
    console.log(this.state.prices)
    return this.state.prices.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <AdditionalPrice
          key={index}
          price={item}
          index={index}
          handleDeletePrice={this.handleDeletePrice}
        />
        )
      });
  }
  renderBasePrice(){
    return(
      <div id="list_prices">
          { this.listPrices() }
      </div>
    )
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {this.renderBasePrice()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

my child component

```
class AdditionalPrice extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      price: this.props.price
    }
    this.handleKeyChange = this.handleKeyChange.bind(this);
    this.handleValueChange = this.handleValueChange.bind(this);
    this.handleDeletePrice = this.handleDeletePrice.bind(this);
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    this.setState({price: nextProps.price})
  }

  handleKeyChange(event){
    let price = this.state.price;
    price.key = event.target.value
    this.setState({price: price})
  }

  handleValueChange(event){
    let price = this.state.price;
    price.value = event.target.value
    this.setState({price: price})
  }

  handleDeletePrice(){
    this.props.handleDeletePrice(this.props.index);
  }

  renderForm(){
    let key = this.state.price.key;
    let value = this.state.price.value;
    return(
      <div className="form-row">
        <div className="col-5">
          <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Key" onChange={this.handleKeyChange} required/>
        </div>
        <div className="col-5">
          <input type="number" className="form-control" placeholder="Value" onChange={this.handleValueChange} required/>
        </div>
        <div className="col-2">
          <button className="btn btn-warning" type="button" onClick={this.handleDeletePrice}>
            <i className="material-icons">delete_forever</i>
          </button>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" className="form-control" name={"base_price["+key+"]"} value={value} />
      </div>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {this.renderForm()}
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

i try to delete a item which was get in children, but it always removes last element instead. I thought it have some problem with index
I want to delete the particular element, it always deletes the last element from the render list array.

please help me to sort this problem

Comment: First you shouldn't set your new array with `=` like you did here:
`let prices = this.state.prices;`. Try `let prices = [...this.state.prices]`;

Comment: Can you please give codepen link. Its hard to guess where is the problem.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Bac3Phi/18827d1dbfd78e091aae649d1dcd657f
https://gist.github.com/Bac3Phi/5088bd13d7c0fb56835bb7f1c5d0f2ae
i use es5 to code

Comment: Double check the content of your `additional_price` gist. It's the same as the first.

Comment: Updated. my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem
my  field in child component haven't set the **value**. see below

```
 <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Key" value={key} onChange={this.handleKeyChange} required/>
```

thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this instead.

```
handleAddNewPrice(){
  const { prices } = this.state;
  let new_price = {"key": "", "value": ""}
  this.setState({ prices: [...prices, new_price] })
}
```

**Edit**

and also this:

```
handleDeletePrice(price_index){
  let prices = [...this.state.prices]; //make a seperate copy of state.
  prices.splice(price_index, 1);
  this.setState({prices: prices});
}
```

Comment: @leafeve Try my second suggestion and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your `props`. The `props.index` is received once, so if you want to the delete function worked you need use `props.index` as a state like `price`. This is sample codes you  need to change in the `AdditionalPrice` Component:

```
this.state = {
  price: this.props.price,
  index: this.props.index
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
   this.setState({
       price: nextProps.price,
       index: nextProps.index
   })
}

handleDeletePrice(){
    this.props.handleDeletePrice(this.state.index);
}
```

Comment: i think my project have problem with material-design library( see [link](https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/) ). the back-end worked really good. Thank you